# A formula to copy the values from a formula to another column

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

I have a column of values created from a formula, I know I can copy the values over to another column by using the clipboard. BUT...I want my spreadsheet to be automatic whilst avoiding the use of VBA coding, so it would be ideal if I could create a formula for the next column which copies the VALUES over to the next column. Maybe an INDEX/MATCH kind of method but one that copies ONLY the values rather than the formulas.

So in essence I want a formula to copy the values from a formula....

Comment: You can use =VALUE(A4), in case A4 is having long formula. Are you check for this?

Comment: That returns an error of #VALUE!

Answer (score 13):

You can use =A4, in case A4 is having long formula

Comment: It won't if formula doesn't result in numeric data type.

Comment: I want the white formula box to be the value created from the previous formula, if i use =a4 then the formula box will be =a4 instead of the value. Also, please note that the value created is text such as ENG ;# IND

Comment: then you have to use VBA

Answer (score 5):

Use =concatenate(). Concatenate is generally used to combine the words of several cells into one, but if you only input one cell it will return that value. There are other methods, but I find this is the best because it is the only method that works when a formula, whose value you wish to return, is in a merged cell.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow why the [CONCATENATE function](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/concatenate-function-870e82a1-d47d-440e-9a77-23e7639eda1d) would be any better at referencing a merged area of cells than simply `=A1` (merged horizontally or vertically). Additionally, this string-based function will turn true numbers into text-that-looks-like-a-number along with all of the problems that come with it.

Comment: This is not an answer to the OP's question, who wants "a formula for the next column which copies the VALUES over to the next column". Using concatenate does not achieve this, since the cell is filled with another formula (namely =concatenate(XX)) instead of a plain value.

Answer (score 3):

For such you must rely on VBA. You can't do it just with Excel functions.

Comment: This seems the only correct answer by definition, since a cell can either be filled with a formule (and no formula IS a plain value, even if it results in a value being displayed), or with a value (but a value cannot refer to another cell so no automation there).

Comment: It was mentioned "avoiding the use of VBA coding"

Answer (score 1):

you can use those functions together with `iferror` as a work around.

try `=IFERROR(VALUE(A4),(CONCATENATE(A4)))`

Comment: Interesting, but it does not answer the OP's question, who wants "a formula for the next column which copies the VALUES over to the next column". Your answer has no effect on the next column, and simply fills the cell with another formula (see the formula box above the cells in Excel) instead of a plain value.

Answer (score 0):

What about trying with `VLOOKUP`? The syntax is:

```
=VLOOKUP(cell you want to copy, range you want to copy, 1, FALSE).
```

It should do the trick.

Answer (score -2):

Copy the cell. Paste special as link.  Will update with original.
No formula though.

Comment: It was asked a formula specifically and the contributor know he can copy